Solutions of $f\circ f=g$ have infinite number of discontinuities if $g$ is a decreasing homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}$
To this question I gave the following answer :
It is clear that $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has a unique fixed point $x_{0}$, and then  $f\left( x_{0}\right)
=f\left( g\left( x_{0}\right) \right) =f^{\left( 3\right) }\left(
x_{0}\right) =g\left( f\left( x_{0}\right) \right) .$ But $x_{0}$ is the unique
fixed point of $g$ so we conclude that $f\left( x_{0}\right) =x_{0}$.
On the other hand if $f\left( x\right) =x$ then $g\left( x\right) =f\left(
f\left( x\right) \right) =f\left( x\right) =x$ so $x_{0}$ is the unique
fixed point of $f$ too.
Now, if $f$ has finite number of discontinuities then $\mathbb{R}$ can be subdivided into disjoint intervals $E_{1},\ldots ,E_{n}$ such that $%
f$ is continuous on each $\overset{\circ }{E}_{i}$ $\left( 1\leq i\leq
n\right) $ and discontinuous at all $n-1$ points of $\bigcup\limits_{1\leq
i\leq n}\partial E_{i}=E$ .
Since $f$ must be bijective then each $\overset{\circ }{E}_{i}\left( 1\leq
i\leq n\right) $ must be an open interval and $f\left( \overset{\circ }{E}%
_{i}\right) \cap E=\left\{ {}\right\} $ $\left( 1\leq i,j\leq
n\right) $ for if not $g$ will be discontinuous. And since $g^{2}\left(
x\right) $ is increasing we must have $f^{\left( 4\right) }\left( \overset{%
\circ }{E}_{i}\right) =\overset{\circ }{E}_{i}\left( 1\leq i\leq n\right) $.
But $f\left( \overset{\circ }{E}_{i}\right) \neq \overset{\circ }{E}%
_{i}\left( 1\leq i\leq n\right) $ for if not we will have $g\left( \overset{%
\circ }{E}_{i}\right) =\overset{\circ }{E}_{i}$ and $g$ will be increasing on
$\overset{\circ }{E}_{i}$ which contradicts the hypothesis on $g$. Then  $%
f\left( \overset{\circ }{E}_{i}\right) =\overset{\circ }{E}_{j}$ (for some $%
j\neq i$) and $\overset{\circ }{E}_{i},$ $f\left( \overset{\circ }{E}%
_{i}\right) ,$ $f^{\left( 2\right) }\left( \overset{\circ }{E}_{i}\right)$,
$f^{\left( 3\right) }\left( \overset{\circ }{E}_{i}\right) $ must all be
different. So $n=4k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_{0}$ must be a point of discontinuity because if $x_{0}\in \overset{%
\circ }{E}_{i}$ then $f\left( \overset{\circ }{E}_{i}\right) =\overset{\circ }{E}_{i}$ and $g$ will be increasing on $\overset{\circ }{E}_{i}$.
Since $f^{\left( 4\right) }$ is increasing then all points in $E\diagdown
\left\{ x_{0}\right\} $ are fixed points of $f^{\left( 4\right) }$ and since
$x_{0}$ is the unique fixed point of $f$ then $x,f\left( x\right) ,$ $%
f^{\left( 2\right) }\left( x\right) ,$ $f^{\left( 3\right) }\left( x\right) $
are all different for all $x\in E\diagdown \left\{ x_{0}\right\} $. Then $%
4k-2$ must a multiple of $4$ which is impossible.
I want to know if there is any mistake on imprecision in the proof and how to make clear and precise the claim :
"$f\left( \overset{\circ }{E}_{i}\right) \cap E=\left\{ {}\right\} $ $\left( 1\leq i,j\leq
n\right) $ for if not $g$ will be discontinuous"
I have stated it by the reasoning that for any $f\left( a\right) \in f\left( 
\overset{\circ }{E}_{i}\right) \cap E$ : $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g\left( x\right) =\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f\left( f\left(
x\right) \right) =\lim_{y\rightarrow f\left( a\right) }f\left( y\right) $ which contradicts the existence of the limit of $g$ at $a$. So is that precise ?

Should I delete the question ?

I wouldn't. Nothing is more annoying than anonymous downvoting.
